# How does Jude's work with masonry relate to his ambition of becoming a scholar?

Tags: thomas-hardy, jude-the-obscure

In *Jude the Obscure*, work that Jude does is masonry - stones and menial labor. His ambition is to become a scholar - books and mental labor.

I'm struggling to see how these relate to each other - how is Jude doing masonry related to his ambitions? Is this to provide a contrast, or is there something else?

Comment: Isn't the point rather that they're *not* related? The contrast between what he *is* and what he *wants* to be is a major theme of the story.

Comment: That's why I mentioned that it could be a contrast, and seems like a point for an answer to elaborate on ;)